# Can ISO images written to USB drives be read under Windows?

Tags: linux, windows, usb, iso-image

I have written an ISO file to a USB drive from Linux using `dd if=file.iso of=/dev/sdb1`.

This works fine, I can then read the data on Linux. Automount works, as does mounting manually (filesystem is detected as ISO9660).

However, Windows won't read the drive. It detects it but only offers to format it.

Is Windows unable to read ISO9660 filesystems on USB drives? Is there some workaround?

Comment: What did you put on the USB drive?  Is it something formatted with a Unix-style file system, or something like exFat, Fat32, or NTFS that Windows can read?

Comment: The filesystem is ISO 9660, which is usually only used for data CDs/DVDs. It can also be used on USB drives, most commonly to create bootable USB drives (for Linux distro installers and such). I wanted to know if Windows could read data from a ISO9660-formatted USB drive, however it appears this is not the case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think windows does not allow iso9660 on a usb stick which responds as mass storage device rather than a cd rom drive.

It only allows you to use a usb stick with u3 support. There are tools to overwrite such sticks to provide the iso image of your choice.

e.g. http://portableapps.com/node/27625

Linux supports the iso9660 file system on every device. (http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl8_mkisofs.htm)

Comment: That was what I was afraid of. Thank you for your reply!

Comment: Have been searching for ages for this....  just weird that Windows is the only platform that doesn't read these. Even my Sony Blu-ray player reads them!
Even here in 2019 it's still the same. And the same goes for Joliet and UDF!

Comment: Windows 7 supports it but looks like the support has been removed on windows 10.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to do it, performed on Windows 10 on 2023-09-06 (yes, I still have Windows 10 and no "Microsoft Cloud")

0. On Windows, install *SysProgs WinCDEmu* available from https://wincdemu.sysprogs.org/
1. On Linux, dump the USB stick content into a file using `dd if=/dev/cdrom of=my_cd.img`. That file will presumably be much smaller than the maximum size allowed by a CD-ROM (i.e. much smaller than ~[700 MB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CD-ROM))
2. Move the file to Windows using your preferred file transfer method (anything from WinSCP to another USB stick)
3. On Windows, open *Explorer* and right-click on the dump file. As *WinCDEmu* has been installed, there should be an option to "mount the file as a virtual disk". Proceed to do so!
4. A new "DVD Drive" appears in *Explorer*'s left-hand bar. You can now open it in the standard way.